# Meaning of maximum number of open files (ulimit -n)

Tags: files, process

Is the maximum number of files open as reported by the "ulimit -n" command a maximum per process owned by that user, or in total for all processes owned by the user.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so checked this myself (wasn't so hard in the end).
It is per process owned by the user.
I tested this by creating a process that opened 1100 files and went to sleep.
It failed with segmentation fault.
I increased the limit to 2000, and the program ran fine.
I could see all 1100 filedescriptors under /prod/{pid}/fd/.
I then ran serveral instances of the program in the background. They all ran fine, and filedescriptiors were there.
I then increased the number of open files to 2200 and reran. It failed again.
The segmation fault is also seen in dmesg.